# How can I load test and performance test an asterisk sip server to find out how many concurrent calls a server can handle?

Tags: asterisk, sip, asteriskami, sip-server, vonage

I have deployed asterisk server in AWS. 
1) I would like to know how many calls it can handle concurrently at the same time?
2) Is it possible to do a load test with several phone numbers? How to simulate it? Any tools?

Comment: This is an infrastructure admin question, not a programming question. I've voted to close it because it's off-topic *here*, but it would be on-topic on ServerFault!

Comment: So will this automatically be listed on server-Fault or should I post it there?

Comment: you need to migrate the question over.

Comment: Where is the migrate option? or should I retype it there? Could you please send me the correct link where I should post it.

Comment: You can use http://sipp.sourceforge.net/ for the sip load testing. This is a open source test tool / traffic generator for the SIP protocol. Hope it will help you at some extent!!